# Gridview row information disappearing after selectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview, master-detail

I have a master/details setup with a GridView and DetailsView both in UpdatePanels.  When the DetailsView is edited and updated, I want these changes to be reflected in the GridView, but without rebinding that data (which could change the selectedItem's sort order among other problems it causes)  On DetailsView ItemUpdated I have the following:

```
    ' Update Gridview '
    ProductsGridView.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(1).Text = e.NewValues("ProductName")
    ProductsGridView.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(2).Text = e.NewValues("Category")
```

This works fine when updating, but when a new item is selected in the Gridview, the updated text disappears.  Why is this and how can I keep that info?  When it is rebound it is fine if it changes position, put until it gets re-bound I would like that data to persist.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:  It was because the cell's text was not being stored in the viewstate.  I added Literal controls to hold the cell's text and updated the literal's text accordingly instead of using the cell's text, like so:

```
        ' Update Gridview '
    CType(ProductsGridView.Rows(selectedIndex).FindControl("thisLit"), Literal).Text = e.NewValues("SomeValue")
    CType(ProductsGridView.Rows(selectedIndex).FindControl("someOtherLit"), Literal).Text = e.NewValues("OtherValue"))
```

The information is now kept in viewstate and works perfectly =)